# Endpoint not found in wcf Get Method but OK in Post methods

Tags: c#, wcf, restful-url

I have wcf rest service.

I wrote POST methods and GET method.
both worked fine until couple of days, but suddenly the Post works fine but all of Get methods return "Endpoint not found".
I've checked milions of times the Url template but it's all OK.
here is my code:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "AddActivities")]
    AddActivitiesResponse AddActivities(List<Activity> activities);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetGeoLocation/{fullAddress}/{account}")]
    GetGeoLocationResponse GetGeoLocation(string fullAddress, string account);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake. I requested with wrong url tempalte.
I sent GetGeoLocation?fullAddress=NY
but I should send GetGeoLocation/NY